# PHP script convert an ainsi file to utf 8

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

As part of a project in **PHP**, I have to deal with a **CSV file** to put data in a **database**.

However, the csv file is encoded in **AINSI** but I would treat data as **UTF-8** for them appear correctly in my database. Do you know a way to automate this conversion?

I already read the function **mb_convert_encoding**, but it works with $string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

if you know for sure that your current encoding is pure ASCII, then you don't have to do anything because ASCII is already a valid UTF-8

But if you still want to convert just to be sure, then you can use iconv

```
$string = iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $string);
```

The IGNORE will discard any invalid characters just in case some were not valid ASCII

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want convert : ASCII -> UTF-8

But AINSI -> UTF-8 ^^